# Is "Beginner" a measurement of time, or skill?

Tags: meaning

The definition is:

> A person just starting to learn a skill or take part in an activity

Which makes me think it's time-related, although I see it's used as a synonym for novice which relates to skill.

What exactly does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we think about these phrases, 'He is an eternal beginner.' (sarcastic- 'he never really learns') and 'He is a quick starter.' (praise- 'he learns pretty fast'), I think *beginner* relates to skill and not time. You begin to learn, and will be a beginner until you have learnt something.

Comment: @mplungjan: You beat me to it by 31 secs! The time it took me to type out the answer :)

Comment: Mplungjan is not a beginner at speed-typing. :-)

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion: Skill unless referring to someone who founded something

You can be a beginner forever.

[beginner](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/beginner)

> someone new to a field or activity   initiate, tiro, tyro, novice
>   unskilled person - a person who lacks technical training
>   abecedarian - a novice learning the rudiments of some subject apprentice, prentice,
>   learner - works for an expert to learn a trade cub, greenhorn,
>   rookie - an awkward and inexperienced youth landlubber, landsman,
>   lubber - an inexperienced sailor; a sailor on the first voyage fledgeling,
>   fledgling, newbie, newcomer, entrant, freshman, neophyte,
>   starter -
>   any new participant in some activity
>   tenderfoot - an inexperienced person (especially someone inexperienced in outdoor living)
>   trainee - someone who is being trained